# CSS: unset and "not set" difference

Tags: javascript, css

Is there any difference between setting a css property to the **unset** value or not setting it at all?

```
#element {
    border: unset;
}

#element {
    /*nothing here!*/
}
```

Also, is the javascript set to **empty string** equivalent to setting to **unset**?

```
element.style.border = "";
element.style.border = "unset"; //same effect always?
```

Comment: `= ""` removes border at all. `= "unset"` set `border="unset"`. In this case the result is the same.

Comment: Given [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset), I don't think there's a difference. But I'm not a CSS expert.

Comment: note that there is a difference in the CSS one in case you have another rule that is setting border. The border:unset will override it while if you set nothing the one defined elsewhere will get used

Comment: If the property isn't set yet there is no difference. But I find `unset` uselful to reset a value to default that has been set in some linked css file that I don't want to change, e.g. in the `bootstrap.css` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From MDN DOCS:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)

> The unset CSS keyword resets a property to its inherited value if the
> property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its initial value
> if not. In other words, it behaves like the inherit keyword in the
> first case, when the property is an inherited property, and like the
> initial keyword in the second case, when the property is a
> non-inherited property.
>
> unset can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand
> all.

In your first case:

```
#element {
    border: unset; // Here the border is set to its default value 
}

#element {
    /*nothing here!*/ In this case you have not used any CSS property on the element so border remains its default value 
}
```

In your second part: No they `""` and `"unset"` don't behave the same:

```
element.style.border = ""; // This will simply have no effect on the border and border will stay whatever it was in CSS
element.style.border = "unset"; // In this case your border will not apply now and default value of the border will be set.
```

**DEMO CODE:**

```js
document.querySelector(".test1").style.background = "";
document.querySelector(".test2").style.background="unset"; // It is set to the default value and no background color is applied
```

```css
.test1,.test2{
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:5px solid red;
  background:blue;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="test1">
</div>

<div class="test2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The unset keyword resets a property to its inherited value if the property naturally inherits from its parent, and to its initial value if not inherited.

See here how the inherit keyword is working

I have taken color as the property instead of border for better understanding.
[Here you can check it live for better clarification](https://codepen.io/BadalChangba/pen/wvzNKxr)

```
color: unset 

is same as setting 

color: inherit
```

inherit here takes the property of the parent element.

```
#element {
    border: unset; 
/*Here the border is inherits its parent property if it has a parent element */
}  

else if does not have parent inheritance it's same as setting

#element {
    /*nothing here!*/ 
  /*In this case you don't have parent inheritance and have default css*/
}
```

You can also check this codepens for better clarification:
[inherit property demonstration](https://codepen.io/BadalChangba/pen/YzGBypP)